# Selected from dropdown menu - keep as selected

Tags: jquery, laravel-5.4

Am using multi-level dropdown for displaying product categories:

```
<div class="dropdown"> <a href="#" id="category_name" class="dropdown-toggle selected_category" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"> <i class="fa fa-list-ul" aria-hidden="true"></i><span>All Category </span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-bottom"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level">
            @foreach($main_categories as $main_category)
              <li id="{{$main_category}}" class="dropdown-submenu main_category"> <a class="maincategory" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{$main_category}}</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li class="dropdown-submenu" id="subcat{{$main_category}}">
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">All</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Boot Cut</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Capri</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Straight Leg</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Skinny</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Ankle/Cropped</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Boyfriend</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Overalls</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wide Leg/Flare</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Relaxed</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mid-rise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Low-rise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Hi-rise</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Easy Boot</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              @endforeach
            </ul>
          </div>
```

When I select Men, it redirects to the page that has the Men products. But the dropdown changes as All Category. How do I make it as selected Option?

Comment: when redirect pass the selected value too . on that page set selected attribute based on value .

Comment: Am using that particular category to be displayed in all the page like layouts. I can't make it in one page

Comment: Maybe keep it in your [Session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session) and do a conditional check if it is present in your session to select the default value.

Comment: how do i do it?

Comment: u have to add java variables i don't have code yet i will comment you soon